# How to connect SQL Server 2008 Express?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, sql-server-2008-express

I can't connect SQL Server Express 2008,I downloaded and installed SQL Server 2008 Express 64Bit, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

And I can't connect to the SQL Server, I tried those options

1. Disable the firewall
2. Restart the SQL Server Service at Sql Server Configuration Service, I have two services that aren't working - SQL Server Agent, SQL Server Browser, only SQL Server is running.

Here is the picture of the message - http://i46.tinypic.com/2zjj051.png

Answer (score 7):

You have to connect to the named instance.

Try connection to .\SQLEXPRESS or swap that out with the name you used for the default instance.

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to connect to it remotely.  It only works locally.

Comment: @Nissan remote connections are disabled by default, but can be enabled: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277

Comment: +1 because it doesn't look like you'll get your answer accepted :(